# MongoDB: Inserting complex data structures

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mean-stack

I've read and searched about MongoDB's JSON-BSON constructions but I do not understand (could not find either) how to have insert documents into documents how to query it.

What I'd like to learn is, if somebody wants to store an array of documents within an array as in school:

```
  const university = mongoose.Schema(
  {
     name : {type : String, require : true, unique : true},
     school : [{
        schoolName : String
    }]
  });
```

And also what is the query to insert within an array of documents if i give like  the name? I am new at MongoDB.

Comment: shouldn't you be referencing your object's structure while UPDATING, just like we do when working with JSON in JavaScript? Look at Mongoose documentation [http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html] for methods to achieve what you want.

Comment: You really need to learn about MongoDB and mongoose and in fact about how NoSQL works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To insert data:

```
const University = mongoose.model('university')
const university = new University({
  name: 'Harvard',
  school: [
    {name: 'One'},
    {name: 'One'},
  ]
})
university.save(function (err, university) {
  console.log(university)
})
```

To query inside an array

```
const University = mongoose.model('university')

// To look for an element in the array
University.find({ 'school.name': 'One' }, function (err, universities) {
  console.log(universities)
})

// To look for an element in an specific position
University.find({ 'school.0.name': 'One' }, function (err, universities) {
  console.log(universities)
})
```

To insert an element inside the array:

To do that is necessary the use of [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) operator that allows to append a value to an array.

```
const University = mongoose.model('university')
University.update(
  { name, 'Harvard' },
  {
    $push: {
      school: {name: 'Three'}
    }
  },
  function (err, universities) {}
)
```

You can go https://university.mongodb.com/ and look for some course, all of them are free and are pretty good explained.

Also reviewing the documentation of [mongodb](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/getting-started/) and [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/) will help you a lot.

Comment: what happen if i got { name : {type : String, require : true, unique : true}, school : [{ schoolName : "Matemathics", teachers:[{name:"Pedro", id: 20}] }] } how can i insert a new teacher? That is my real question

Comment: that would be your mission buddy, just a tip "is has to do with $push operator"